# How to implement a Prestashop Front Controller

Tags: module, controller, seo, prestashop

Sorry for my poor English.

I'm developing a Prestashop module to list services in a block on the Front-end. The module is complete but this uses ugly URLs like "http://www.mysite.com/modules/servicescatalog/showservicedata.php?srvId=1"

The client of this module wrote to me to make this URL SEO Friendly, like "http://www.mysite.com/modules/servicescatalog/showservicedata/service-1"

Searching in Google I think the the solution is to implement a Front Controller but I don't know how to manage this. Does anyone know how to implement ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a new .htaccess file inside your module folder

.htacces example

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# URL rewriting module activation
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^showservicedata/service-([0-9]+)$ showservicedata.php?srvId=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make `SEO url` your module, then go to `Preference tab > SEO & URL` and the add new. Set up the module with what you want.

Comment: but he won't find his page on the 'Page' list

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here. It has detailed instructions on adding a custom front controller.

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/342774-add-custom-php-page-prestashop-16/